# Sum - Groupby Values in ssrs Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Here I designed the date as group by.based on the date the third column values will show 1,2,2 for each date .Now I need to show as 5 instead of 1,2,2.

[image]

How can I sum the values.If i add the total it shows as 10.But for first date i need 5 and next date i need 5 ? How can I do this?

Comment: If you are only after one detail line per date, why not SUM by date in the SQL rather than in the SSRS?

Comment: Do you want 1,2,2 and a _total_ line with 5 or just 5?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you should see three Row Groups at the bottom of the screen. Just delete the third group which is usually named "Details". Make sure that third column has a `Sum` around the column. With the details just grouped by date, it will roll those details into one line and sum the values.

Another option is to add subtotals. Right-click on the date field and add a row outside and below group. Now you will get both the detail lines and a subtotal by date. It's good practice to play around with combinations of layout because grouping is a big part of report design.